# Python no me reconoce la función reduce

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Estaba revisando [este tutorial](https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php) porque no sabía como usar una operación de reducción en python pero al tratar de correr

```
def sum_of_minimums(numbers):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, map(lambda row: min(row), numbers))
```

en un python 3.6.0 me arroja el error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/runner/frameworks/python/cw-2.py", line 111, in wrapper
>
> func()
>
> File "main.py", line 5, in fixed_tests
>
> test.assert_equals(sum_of_minimums([ [ 7,9,8,6,2 ], [6,3,5,4,3], [5,8,7,4,5] ]),9)
>
> File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 2, in sum_of_minimums
>
> return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, map(lambda row: min(row), numbers))
>
> NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined

En Python versión 2.7.6 funciona perfectamente

¿Desapareció esta función o como puedo referenciarla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está en la librería `functools`.

```py
from functools import reduce
```

Ya no forma parte de las funciones `built-in`. Según [Guido van Rossum](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum), es mejor utilizar un bucle u otra función.

Por ejemplo: `sum_of_minimums` se puede escribir así:

```py
def sum_of_minimums(numbers):
    return sum([min(row) for row in numbers])
```

Comment: ohh es cierto, tienes idea de por qué se pasó allí? si es la misma?

Comment: Pienso que es la misma. https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Comment: Vaya, ya hallé el motivo según el creador de python, https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196 podrías agregar un extracto por si alguien tiene sus dudas de si es la misma y por qué ya no forma parte de las funciones built in?